# React app works fine in Chrome but gets invariant exception in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I have a weird issue where the current way i've setup this react app has it failing to load in IE, It also has a similiar issue on older iPhones.

I have cut down the app to the smallest that replicates the issue.

https://github.com/dalefrancis88/Portal

After an...

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

You can connect to http://localhost:3020/admin it will show three lines in chrome...

```
qwerty
header
wrapper
```

but in IE it will only show

```
qwerty
```

Opening the dev tools in IE will then show it to have the invariant exception.

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I am unsure what is causing this and not sure where to go from here. The fact it works in chrome and not IE is weird to me since its a JS issue.